# Customize stuck in refresh loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress multisite network.

When I'm trying to access the Customize admin page, it just keeps refreshing and says "You have logged in successfully". This applies to all websites within the network. I've tried to use the standard theme, doesn't work.

I tried to install a fresh installation of WordPress on my localhost, that worked fine. So it's something wrong within the multisite network.

I can't really start disabling plugins etc. because all websites are live with real visitors.

Any ideas what might cause this problem?

Comment: Are you using multiple domains?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem, and found that it was caused by the plugin WP-Copyright-Protection. Apparently this plugin prevents modifying the contents of an iFrame, which is needed for the Customize function. Disabling the plugin temporarily was all that was needed.